# Casting two enums with identical properties to the same type

Tags: swift, generics, enums, swiftui, type-conversion

I have two enum types in my program which I want to use to populate my view. I would like to pass them into the same for-loop. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
enum BaseStat : String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    var id: String{self.rawValue}
    case str = "Strength"
    case dex = "Dexterity"
    case con = "Constitution"
    case int = "Intelligence"
    case wis = "Wisdom"
    case cha = "Charisma"
}

enum Skill : String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    var id: String{self.rawValue}
    case acr = "Acrobatics"
    case ani = "Animal Handling"
    case arc = "Arcana"
    case ath = "Athletics"
    case dec = "Deception"
    case his = "History"
}

struct listView: View {
    @Binding var isStats : Bool
    var body: some View {
        ForEach((isStats ? BaseStat : Skill).allCases) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This fails since BaseStat and Skill are different types.  I've also tried assigning them to a variable, but I've been unable to find a type cast that works for this.  String does not work:

```
var listVal: String {
    switch isStat {
    case true: 
        return BaseStat
    case false:
        return Skill
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend same approach as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65183159/12299030.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple enum types list all cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65182599/multiple-enum-types-list-all-cases)

Comment: Could you perhaps shed some light on exactly how you plan to use the cases inside the loop? Are the actual enum what you're after, or do you simply want to combine the strings in some manner?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to display just the id of the case inside the ForEach view? If yes, try to create dedicated lists of type `[String]` and switch between them.

My working example:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

enum BaseStat : String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    var id: String{self.rawValue}
    case str = "Strength"
    case dex = "Dexterity"
    case con = "Constitution"
    case int = "Intelligence"
    case wis = "Wisdom"
    case cha = "Charisma"
}

enum Skill : String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    var id: String{self.rawValue}
    case acr = "Acrobatics"
    case ani = "Animal Handling"
    case arc = "Arcana"
    case ath = "Athletics"
    case dec = "Deception"
    case his = "History"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isStats = true
    var list1 = Skill.allCases.map { $0.id }
    var list2 = BaseStat.allCases.map { $0.id }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Switch") {
                self.isStats.toggle()
            }
            
            ForEach(isStats ? list2 : list1, id:\.self) { value in
                Text("\(value)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you :)