# Can you pass more than one data source in List() in Swift UI?

Tags: listview, swiftui, enums

I have 3 enums that I have made CaseIterable.  I am wondering if there is a way to pass all three enums in List at once.

What I am able to do:

```
VStack {
            List(OtherWoundsName.allCases, id: \.self) {name in
                Text(name.rawValue)
                }
        }
```

Is there a way to pass 2 other enums into this.  I want to display all three sources of data in a list.  My have a lot enums, and they are quite long (unto 20 cases) and really don't want to create a struct and enter each one in manually.  I went this way for type safety and to reduce spelling errors.

ie.

```
var allOtherWounds = [
BillingData(name: OtherWoundsName.secondaryclosure_name.rawValue, code: OtherWoundsCode.secondaryclosure_code.rawValue, value: OtherWoundsValue.secondaryclosure_value.rawValue),
BillingData(name: OtherWoundsName.musclerepair_name.rawValue, code: OtherWoundsCode.musclerepair_code.rawValue, value: OtherWoundsValue.musclerepair_value.rawValue),
BillingData(name: OtherWoundsName.woundone_name.rawValue, code: OtherWoundsCode.woundone_code.rawValue, value: OtherWoundsValue.woundone_value.rawValue)
```

]

This would take too long!

So I would like to do in theory:

```
VStack {
        List(OtherWoundsName.allCases, OtherWoundsCode.allCases, OtherWoundsValue.allCases, id: \.self) {name, code, value in
            Text(name.rawValue)      
            Text(code.rawValue)
            Text(value.rawValue)}}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65183159/12299030?

Comment: It does, thanks - a bit more code than the other answer but thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than iterating on the enum cases directly, you can also iterate through a index range, then access each case with index:

```swift
List(0..<OtherWoundsName.allCases.count) { index in
    Text(OtherWoundsName.allCases[index].rawValue)
    Text(OtherWoundsCode.allCases[index].rawValue)
    Text(OtherWoundsValue.allCases[index].rawValue)
}
```

Comment: That worked so well!  Saved me so much time!